# Should you resample rasters before or after raster calculator operations?

Tags: raster, raster-calculator, resampling

I struggle to understand if rasters should be resampled before or after doing some arithmetic. For example:

Suppose I have a DTM and DSM of an AOI which were produced from the same instrument, but the DTM is 1 m resolution and the DSM is 25 cm. If I want a CHM output layer at 50 cm, would you:

1. Resample both the DTM, DSM up/down to 50 cm, then use raster calculator? or;
2. Create the CHM from the native resolutions, creating a 25 cm CHM, then upsample to 50 cm?

Is there a precedent for this?

Comment: Seems like an easy experiment for you to try.  What were your results?

Comment: But the results will just be the results. I'm wondering if one method is more accurate than the other from a statistical stand point? I don't know how to determine that myself

Comment: Surely you could compare the two outputs to the input.  I'm surprised that you're not curious enough to even try.